PowerAutomate Flow Updated but Still Using Approvers from the Old SharePoint List
I made a copy of my existing approval flow as well as it's related SharePoint list that has all approvers emails in them and renamed them both. Even after updating the SharePoint list name in the Get Items operation, when I run the flow, it still picks up the approvers from the old SharePoint list. Any thing I need to be updating? I tried reupdating all the connections, dynamic contents, but problem still exists. Any advice will be very much appreciated.
